# Create an interaction between two categorical columns in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two multi-level categorical columns stored in `df`:

1. `dow` represents the day of week (seven catagories mapped to integers: 1, 2, ..., 7).
2. `type` represents four types of observation (four categories mapped to integers: 1, 2, 3, 4).

How can I create an interaction (i.e., the multiplication) of these two columns in PySpark?

I know how to encode them using `OneHotEncoder`. However, I'm not sure how to go about the feature engineering process to account for all 28 combinations (7 x 4 possible cases), especially because `OneHotEncoder` returns sparse vectors.

For the purpose of this question, assume my pyspark dataframe `df` looks as follows:

| dow | type | target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 200 |
| 1 | 2 | 222 |
| 1 | 7 | 229 |

Where `dow` can take on seven different values and `type` can take on four. Is there a built-in way to create interactions between these two columns in order to account for all possible combinations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do integer encoding by multiplying `dow` by 10 and adding `type` to it to create individual integers for each unique value:

```py
(
    df
    .select(
        (F.col('dow') * F.lit(10) + F.col('type')).alias('result'), 
        'dow', 
        'type'
    )
    .show()
)

+------+---+----+
|result|dow|type|
+------+---+----+
|    11|  1|   1|
|    12|  1|   2|
|    17|  1|   7|
+------+---+----+
```

Comment: Are you multiplying by 10 to avoid two combinations resulting in the same product? Love that pep8 formatting too. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, since you have integers 1 < 7, the multiply by 10 allows me to treat each tens place as a data point